# Has this variation of Hochschild cohomology been studied?

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, hochschild-cohomology

Let $k$ be a field, and let $A$ be a commutative $k$-algebra.

Let $M$ be an abelian group, and assume that it an $n$-$A$-module. That is: it has $n$ different $A$-module structures, and they are pairwise compatible. (For example, if $M_1,\dots,M_n$ are $A$-modules, then $M_1 \otimes_k \dots \otimes_k M_n$ is clearly an $n$-$A$-module).

Then, for each $i$, consider the $A$-modules

$$
  \operatorname{Ext}^i_{A^{\otimes_k n}}(A, M) \,.
$$

For $n=2$ this is just Hochschild cohomology. Here, $M$ has the structure of an $A^{\otimes_k n}$-module where the $i$-th $A$ operates on $M$ via the $i$-th action.

Has this been considered in the literature? are there any applications of this construction?

Comment: This reminds me of an interpretation of Gerstenhaber-Schack cohomology of bialgebras as Ext in certain category of «tetramodules» &c (see [Shoikhet's arXiv:0907.3335](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.3335) for details).

Comment: How are you using the n different A-module structures on M?

Comment: Well, these structures gives $M$ the structure of an $A\otimes_k A \otimes_k A \otimes_k \dots \otimes_k A$-module.